# What does the "operation name" reference?

Tags: graphql

I'm learning about GraphQL and I'm very interested in the `operation name` the part of the query that comes after the `query` or `mutation` (depending on the root query type). I found a couple of code examples using the operation name, and I'm confused as to where they come from? There seems to be no references in the code about them, and they seem completely arbitrary.

```
query Welcome {
  echo (email: "hi@example.com")
}
```

and

```
query HeroNameQuery {
  hero {
    name
  }
}
```

I don't understand why a given schema can't just contain the queries and types that follow (eg. `user`, `article`, `order`, etc.), and I don't understand the namespacing system and the operation name provides any sort of advantage.

https://github.com/mugli/learning-graphql/blame/master/7.%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20GraphQL%20Type%20System.md#L436

http://graphql.org/docs/queries/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the name can be omitted (I think `query` too) if you're only sending one. I believe the names are basically used for stored queries. You could put those on the server and execute them by name rather than sending the whole query...I believe that's the idea, but I'm a GQL noob too.

Comment: very explicit text - https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#operation-name

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In GraphiQL you can choose from a list of queries specified by the operation name. Here's some screenshots to help make this make sense.

[image]

When you have two mutations / queries side-by-side and they don't have an operation name you can't run them.

When they have operation names they can be listed when you click the play / run button.

[image]

This is the biggest case for having an operation name that I've seen so far.

But it's not necessary because when you just have run query / mutation that's what's gonna run.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The Query/Mutation name is optional. You can use it on the backend for stored queries if your backend supports it. However, it is generally used for logging. You can use a unique name for each query/mutation. Then, when you are having problems, you can grep through your logs for the query name to see what was happening with that specific query.

Comment: I read that in the docs too (https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#operation-name). The confusing part is, the client side optionally sets the query operation name to whatever they want, so i can't see how that's useful for debugging via server side logs!

Comment: @spinkus yes, the operation name doesn't necessarily convey meaning if the client has merely generated it. But it could still be useful for inspecting logs in case you have access to the client and can find out which query they sent.

Answer (score 7):

That's a great question. The operation name is pretty much up to you on what you want to call it. However, you do need it when you pass in query / mutation parameters like so:

```
// GraphQL Query

query Welcome ($data: String!) {
  echo (email: $data) {
    name
  }
}

// GraphQL Variables

{
  "data": "hi@example.com"
}
```

As for the return fields, you must write out the subfields of a given typed selection since GraphQL's philosophy is that everything is strongly-typed and the client dictates *exactly* what data it needs down to the subfield.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you have a bigger project to work on then it is necessary to add the name of the mutation because unnamed graphQL queries can hinder the important monitoring logs from the (Application Performance Monitoring - APM) like NewRelic.

[image: APM Logs]